# toggling the checkbox to show markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

> > I am trying to show the markers based on checkbox selection and unselection,
> >     but the problem i am facing is when the user continuously checks and unckecks the checkbox the marker will be multiplied and shown on maps.
> >     Can anyone help me resolving this.

My html file is below looks like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" style="float: right;" id="w" ng-click="getworkers()"></input>
```

my javascript code to show markers and clusters is below

```
$scope.getworkers = function(){         
    clearOverlays();       
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(document.getElementById('w').checked){
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.responseWorker.length;i++){                

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.responseWorker[i].rep_lat,$scope.responseWorker[i].rep_lon); 
        lat = $scope.responseWorker[i].rep_lat;
        lng=$scope.responseWorker[i].rep_lon;
        name=$scope.responseWorker[i].rep_name;
        address=$scope.responseWorker[i].rep_address;

         bounds.extend(latlng);
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map:map,
             animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
             icon: "lib/images/green-dot.png"
         });     
         clusterobj.markers.push(marker);

        //Info window
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();                        
            var content =  "<table>" +"<head><h4>All Worker Details</h4></head>"+
             "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td> "+name+" </td> </tr>" + "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td> "+address+"</td></tr>"+ "</table>";


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
            return function() {
                if (infowindow)
                    infowindow.close();
                 infowindow.setContent(content); 
              infowindow.open(map, marker);                 
                //map.setZoom(7);
            };
          })(marker, content, infowindow));    

            };
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            var mcOptions = {styles: [{
                gridSize: 40,
                height: 53,
                url: "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png",
                width: 53
                },
            ]};      
            clusterobj.mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,clusterobj.markers,mcOptions);
    }
    else if(!document.getElementById('w').checked)
    {
     clusterobj.mc.clearMarkers();                  

    }

    },2000);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the user continuously checks and unckecks the checkbox the marker
>   will be multiplied and shown on maps

The reason that markers keep multiplying is that the code that creates markers was generated inside a for loop and is triggered everytime the checkbox is ticked. What I would suggest you to do is to:

1. create a function that generates your markers using a for loop. This function only runs once.
2. create separate function that will hide the markers when checkbox is unchecked. Another separate function that will show the markers when the checkbox is ticked.

Demo code is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove).